# Placement of 'import' in a Python script

Tags: python, import, location

This is about placement of 'import' command 
(a general question - found hard to seek similar questions)

Give *somefunction* requires *a*, and *somefunction* is in a separate file.
I see three possible alternatives.  If I am to import something in a function, which one is a better practice? Or is there any other option?

```
## main command lines
import a                   # choice 1: import in a main command line
import file.somefunction

somefunction()

## function command lines in a separate file
import a                   # choice 2: import ahead of function

def somefunction():
    import a               # choice 3: import within function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general guidance per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module
>   comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

That said, people sometimes put imports inside functions in the rare cases where the module should only be imported in the event of a particular function call (typically when the module isn't always available, or to avoid a circular import, or if the import does something expense and needs to be deferred).  For example, see the [server adapters for the *itty* micro-webframework](https://github.com/toastdriven/itty/blob/master/itty.py#L804).

Another practice is to place some of the imports right after `if __name__ == '__main__'` for modules that are only used in the main section.  That prevents unnecessary sub-imports when someone imports the current module.

Comment: Thank you so much for improving my question and for your answer

Comment: Hope my limited language and coding ability did not bother you

Answer (score 0):

I believe regular practise would be to import the modules wherever they are to be used. So if a is used by somefunction, which is located in a separate file, then one would have `import a` at the top of that file that somefunction resides in. 
Then, in your other file, you would import file.somefunction and use that as necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer 
I will follow your practice!

Answer (score 0):

The general guidance (per PEP 8) is to place the imports at the top of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had no idea about the general guidance!